# How to create customized colors with flask and BULMA?

Tags: css, flask, bulma

My app has a real time table and one of the columns is the status of the order of the row. My question is how could i make that each status (which i obtain in the server and send as a incoming new status id) could be rendered as a icon and have some colors attached to that id.

My idea is to pass only the id from the server (like i do now) and have a static file folder with all the svg's with its file name being the same as the id. and on every new emit the html href changes.

**For the color part im a bit stuck looking on how to customize bulma so i can create custom classes that represent a color for every status, how would i do that on bulma ?**

EDIT:

what i have tried is to emit a full information pack for every status update to the table

```
data_from_sql=PosibleStates.query.filter_by(id=new_satus_id).first()

emit('update_row', {'font_awesome_icon':data_from_sql.icon,
'color':data_from_sql.color, 'abort_button_enabled':data_from_sql.abortable})
```

this data is from a sqlalchemy table i have that links every status to a set of features like the ones above. I want to get rid of this table and manage everything through the front end. and just :

```
emit('update_row':new_satus_id)
```

and the front end manages the rest...

Comment: i edited the question explaining well what i tried.

Comment: Note that in the example i send font awesome icons, i dont do that anymore because i use svg files instead as i explained in the first paragraph, so my main doubt is how to render custom colors and custom disable flags that are atached to it in the front end, the disabled part is just that when a user opens a popup a button cant be pressed, i dont know how to do that either.